# Python: Easier way of calculating variable with multiple summations

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I am given this formula for solving for a variable:
[image]

I have all the variables stored in lists. For example, I have a list F that has all the Fsub i values. 
As of now, the way I'm solving this is as follows:

```
#Getting first term
one_over_sigma2 = list()

for elem in sigma_terms:

    _squared = 1/ elem**2

    one_over_sigma2.append(_squared)

first_term = sum(one_over_sigma2)
```

However, this seems like a very inefficient way, particularly for when summations get more messy. I am wondering if there is any better way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of creating an intermediary list, just perform the sum over a generator statement: `sum(1/sigma**2 for sigma in sigma_terms)`

Comment: This seems to work similar to list comprehensions. So for the second term could i just write : `sum(x**2/y**2 for x,y in zip(f_terms, sigma_terms)`